# SshDroid SCP: connection refused

Tags: linux, ssh, android, scp

I'm trying to copy some files from my PC to my android device, yet I'm having trouble with the transfer. I connected easily using SSHDroid app, but scp returns `ssh: Exited : Error connecting : Connection refused.`

I typed the following line: `scp user@PC:path/of/file user@android:destination/folder/path`

I'm trying to transfer an audio file... if it matters. also the user and host of the android device appear as something along the lines of `u0_312s@K3123` .

EDIT: After some more tries and adding `-P port` to the command i get a new error: `Couldn't set nonblocking`

Comment: are you able to `ssh` the android? What do you see in the logs of the "server"?

Comment: I am in the android... i think. SSHdroid logs say: 1) chmod failed, 2) Password auth succeeded ... , 3) child connection from ...

Comment: If you are on Android, do you have `sshd` server running on your PC?

Comment: I dont really know... I assume I do. I installed the openSSH package which should have the server also, right? Im on arch.

Comment: no, it is `openssh-server`. You can check by `service ssh status` or `service sshd status`

Comment: sorry, but I don't have the service command, and I don't know how else to check for status. also entering sshd in the prompt returns sshd re-exec requires execution with an absolute path

Answer (score 0):

If you want to transfer file from your computer (`PC` in your example), it should be enough to run it in this form:

```
scp /path/of/file user@android:destination/folder/path
```

Otherwise it would try to connect also to your PC, which is not required.

Comment: doing so gives the following error: "Error resolving ' ' port ' '. No address associated with hostname

Comment: of course you need to use the hostname of your phone, that is resolvable from your computer, or rather direct ip

Comment: i did keep the user and host that are shown on the prompt, something like u0_312s@K3123 . i also tried changing the phone user and host with root@'phone_ip' which just says connection refused